# Conditional random vector distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$(X_n,Y_n)$ has a density $f_{X_n,Y_n}(s,t)=n(n-1)(t-s)^{n-2}1_{0<s<t<1}$.
It is independent of variable $N$ with $P(N=n)=\frac{1}{(e-2)n!}, n=2,3,...$

How to show that $(X_N,Y_N)$ has density $f(s,t)=\frac{e^{t-s}}{e-2}1_{0<s<t<1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Law of total probability, 
$$F_{X_N,Y_N}(s,t)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \mathbb P(X_N\leq s,Y_N\leq t ~|~ N=n)\mathbb P(N=n)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty F_{X_n,Y_n}(s,t)\mathbb P(N=n).$$
We also used here that $(X_n,Y_n)$ does not depend on $N$, and therefore 
$$\mathbb P(X_N\leq s,Y_N\leq t~|~ N=n) = \mathbb P(X_n\leq s,Y_n\leq t~|~ N=n) = \mathbb P(X_n\leq s,Y_n\leq t).$$
Next find $f_{X_N,Y_N}(s,t)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial s\partial t}F_{X_N,Y_N}(s,t)$ and get 
$$f_{X_N,Y_N}(s,t)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty f_{X_n,Y_n}(s,t)\mathbb P(N=n).$$
Calculate the last sum and get answer.

Comment: Why should I calculate the last sum if I have already $f_{X_N,Y_N}(s,t)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial s\partial t}F_{X_N,Y_N}(s,t)$?

Comment: You should calculate it since you have $f_{X_n,Y_n}(s,t)$ and the task is to get   $f_{X_N,Y_N}(s,t)$. And if you found previously the value of $F_{X_n,Y_n}(s,t)$ and $F_{X_N,Y_N}(s,t)$, you can simply find the derivative.

Comment: IOW, the détour by the CDFs suggested here is quite unnecessary.